# Draw in image programmatically

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I'm having trouble with my bingo application,I tried drawing a circle programmatically whenever a number is picked in my number generator.

I tried this code, that draws the circle in image then save it to the `documentsDirectory`. I also have a load implementation that I load it in the view when I call it.

//draw

```
-(void)draw
{
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"GeneralBingoResult.png"];
    UIImage *imageWithCircle1 = [self imageByDrawingCircleOnImage1:image];

    // save it to documents

    NSString *documentsPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                                   NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
    NSString *filePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Output.png"];
    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageWithCircle1);
    [imageData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
    NSLog(@"Saved new image to %@", filePath);

UIImage *image1 = [self loadImage];
    [imageToDisplay setImage:image1];

}
```

//draws the circle in the image

```
- (UIImage *)imageByDrawingCircleOnImage1:(UIImage *)image
{
    // begin a graphics context of sufficient size
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(image.size);
    // draw original image into the context
    [image drawAtPoint:CGPointZero];
    // get the context for CoreGraphics
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // set stroking color and draw circle
    [[UIColor redColor] setStroke];

    // make circle rect 5 px from border
    CGRect circleRect = CGRectMake(420,40,
                                   90,
                                   90);
    circleRect = CGRectInset(circleRect, 5, 5);

    // draw circle
    CGContextStrokeEllipseInRect(ctx, circleRect);

    // make image out of bitmap context
    UIImage *retImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    // free the context
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return retImage;
}
```

//loads from doc directory

```
- (UIImage*)loadImage
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, 
                                                         NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString* path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent: 
                      [NSString stringWithString: @"Output.png"] ];
    UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];
    return image;
}
```

I successfully draw a circle in my image, but my problem is when I save the image with the circle in `documentsDirectory` I want to be able to load the saved image and draw with that image again. Or rather how am I going to implement it like a bingo app, like this:

Example: 
First,Number 7 is picked in the number generator.
Output:

[image: [IMG]http://i186.photobucket.com/albums/x3/arkei8105/1-1.jpg[/IMG]]

Next, number 55 is picked. It adds another circle to the number.
Output:

[image: [IMG]http://i186.photobucket.com/albums/x3/arkei8105/2.jpg[/IMG]]

By the way, I'm using a `UIScrollview`. And I am implementing it in the `ScrollViewDidEndScrolling`. Thanks.

I also tried this code, but it only shows one circle every time the `UIScrollView` stops.

```
 - (void) scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation:(UIScrollView *)scrollview{

    if ([[images objectAtIndex:index] intValue] == 1){
                [circle setFrame:CGRectMake(420,40,90,90)];
                [self.view addSubview:circle];       
    }else if([[images objectAtIndex:index] intValue] == 2){
                [circle setFrame:CGRectMake(460,40,90,90)];
                [self.view addSubview:circle];   
     }
}
```

Comment: Are you able to draw circle at different frame on static image? If yes then you just need to replace same image in document folder for all possibilities.Is your numbers are static? If yes then 25 frames for circle you need to draw.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your easiest option is to create an image in photoshop or other similar program which is the required size and which has a transparent background. Save this as a .png file. Then, when you want to add the circles over the board, you just have to add a new UIImageView over the correct location in the grid:

```
UIImageView *circle;
circle = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xLocation, yLocation, myCircleWidth, myCircleHeight)];
circle.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myCircle.png"];
[self.view addSubview:circle];
```

An alternate option is to create a view that inherits from UIView. You can add methods to this class which allow you to set locations as circled. Then inside the drawRect code you just draw circles over all the locations which have been marked.

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
// Circle your marked locations here
}
```

The final step in this case is to add your new view over your original view which contains the BINGO board.

EDIT:

Here is extended sample code for doing a view overlay. First, OverlayView.h:

```
@interface OverlayView : UIView {

}

- (void)clearPoints;
- (void)addPointX:(int)whichX Y:(int)whichY;
@end
```

Note that I use the C++ vector here, so this is in OverlayView.mm file:

```
#import "OverlayView.h"
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#include <vector>

@implementation OverlayView

std::vector<int> points;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {
        // Initialization code
        [self setOpaque:NO];
        [self setUserInteractionEnabled:false];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    if (points.size() == 0)
        return;
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(); 
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 15.0);

    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 1.0, 0.0, 0, 0.5);
    for (int x = 0; x < points.size(); x++)
        CGContextStrokeEllipseInRect(context, CGRectMake(points[x]%width-resolution/2,
                                                         points[x]/width-resolution/2,
                                                         resolution, resolution));

}

- (void)dealloc {
    //printf("Deallocating OverlayView\n");
    [super dealloc];
}


- (void)clearPoints {
    points.resize(0);
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

- (void)addPointX:(int)whichX Y:(int)whichY {
    points.push_back(whichX+whichY*width);

    [self setNeedsDisplay];
    printf("Adding point (%d,%d)\n", whichX, whichY);
}
```

You just need to add this view inside the same view as your board. Call the addPoint function to add a circle centered at that point. You'll need to defined the resolution and width of your view for yourself.

Comment: Hi, i already tried this. I've put my code in the `UIScollViewDidEnd`. But I dont know how to put it over another. I wanna try adding a subview to a subview. But is it possible?

Comment: So I am going to make a new class named Overlay right? How am I going to use add this in ScrollViewDidEndScrolling?

Comment: I'm assuming that your BINGO board is embedded inside the scroll view already. If so, you don't use it inside ScrollViewDidEndScrolling. You just add it inside the ScrollView in one or all of the init functions, or add it manually inside interface builder. (When you add it, make sure you keep a reference to it.) Then, each time you want to circle a location, you just call addPoint to circle that location. Since it is inside the scroll view, it will automatically scroll with the view.

Comment: I have a slot machine that consist of those numbers. I use UIScrollView for slot machine. Whenever UIScrollView stops at a specific number, I will show another view that consists of the above image. How with that?

Comment: So, that is an important detail I didn't understand before. Your suggestion is fine, though, to just show another view with the board and the overlay view, with the overlay view showing the circles for the board.

Comment: I'm using the code slightly differently than you, but I just call     `[overlay addPointX:x Y:y];` (the overlay is already inside my view and I have a pointer to it in the variable `overlay`.

Comment: Ah, so It's like this: 1st, I make a new class for the overlay. then import it in my BingoViewController right? Then whenever I need the circle I just call `[overlay addPointX:x Y:y];` right?  And can I clear something Is it `overlay.mm` with two m?

Comment: Yes, I think you understand now.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11542/discussion-between-kobe-o4-and-nathan-s)

Answer (score 1):

Just paste it over top of your bingo board via UIImageView at the correct coordinates (The bingo boards are all the same size, I assume?  Should be easy to calculate).  Or am I missing what you are trying to do?

Comment: Like a bingo game. like the image above.

Comment: Yeah...the bottom one is just three images, so what is the problem?

Comment: You need to ask a more specific question then.  Not just "how to I implement X".  To me that question means "How can I draw the circle on  top of the bingo board.  That is the question I answered.  I will not write an explanation of how to make what I see in the video you sent.

Comment: Im not that good in english, so It's hard explaining what I meant. What question should I ask then?

Comment: Try to ask your question more specifically.  Tell us exactly what you are having trouble with.  It doesn't really matter what you "want to do".  Tell us what you are trying to do, and where it is not working.

Comment: `UIImageView *imageView ＝ [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:circle]];`  This is how you reuse a UIImage.  See the docs (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImageView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 0):

Just give this a try

```
UIImage *image1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.png"]; 
UIImage *image2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image2.png"]; 

CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(width, height);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext( newSize );

[image1 drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];

[image2 drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height) blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:0.8];
UIImage *finalImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want animations like bingo app than you can use Cocos2D framework for building your app.